# How to wait for a child process to finish?

Tags: c, windows

I have a small application which starts a defined process on a new desktop, thus making it invisible for the user.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
int ExitCode = 0;

PWSTR Arguments = PathGetArgs( GetCommandLine() );
if ( NULL == Arguments )
{
    printf( "\nPathGetArgs Failed. Error = %d", GetLastError() );
    return 1;
}

std::wstring Args( Arguments );

std::wstring DesktopName = L"myDesktop";
bool bRetVal = false;
STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;

ZeroMemory( &StartupInfo, sizeof( StartupInfo ) );
StartupInfo.cb = sizeof( StartupInfo );

StartupInfo.lpDesktop = const_cast<LPWSTR>( DesktopName.c_str() );

PROCESS_INFORMATION ProcessInformation;
ZeroMemory( &ProcessInformation, sizeof( ProcessInformation ) );

HDESK Desktop = CreateDesktop( DesktopName.c_str(), NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL );
if ( Desktop == NULL )
{
    printf( "\nCreateDesktop Failed. Error = %d", GetLastError() );
    goto Error;
}

if ( !SetThreadDesktop( Desktop ) )
{
    printf( "\nSetThreadDesktop Failed. Error = %d", GetLastError() );
    goto Error;
}

if ( !CreateProcess( NULL, Arguments, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &StartupInfo, &ProcessInformation ) )
{
    if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED )
        ExitCode = ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED;
    printf( "\nCreateProcess Failed. Error = %d", GetLastError() );
    goto Error;
}

DWORD status;
status = WaitForSingleObject( ProcessInformation.hProcess, INFINITE );
if ( status == WAIT_FAILED )
{
    printf( "\nWaitForSingleObject Failed. Error = %d", GetLastError() );
    goto Error;
}

DWORD ProcessExitCode;
if ( !GetExitCodeProcess( ProcessInformation.hProcess, &ProcessExitCode ) )
{
    ExitCode = 0;
    printf( "\nGetExitCodeProcess Failed. Error = %d", GetLastError() );
    goto Error;
}

ExitCode = ProcessExitCode;

Error:
if ( Desktop )
    CloseDesktop( Desktop );
if ( ProcessInformation.hThread )
    CloseHandle( ProcessInformation.hThread );
if ( ProcessInformation.hProcess )
    CloseHandle( ProcessInformation.hProcess );

return ExitCode;
}
```

Basically everything is working fine, however there is a small problem. Let's say, I want to start Process1. Process1 will be started on a new desktop, everything is good. If Process1 however creates a new child process (Process2), and then the original Process1 exits, then I get an error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)
```

As far as I can tell, this happens because, if Process1 exits, then WaitForSingleObject will stop waiting, and the desktop will also be destroyed, so Process2 can't run on the specified desktop anymore.

Does anyone have an idea how I could wait for Process2 to finish? Or is there something I did wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you tagging C? `std::wstring` is C++

Comment: @klutt because it was written in C++ originally and I am rewriting it in C, and I haven't finished yet. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects).

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, Job objects works, however not ideal in this case. If I have an installer, and it starts multiple processes, and at the end of the installation it starts a process, which is running in the taskbar, then the process will never end. What I want is, that wait untill the installation is completed. If a process is started which is running in the taskbar (which is the app itself), then quit. Or can I somehow "decide" which process doesn't belong to the installation?

Comment: *"it starts a process, which is running in the taskbar"* - Not sure what that is supposed to mean. *"can I somehow "decide" which process doesn't belong to the installation?"* - What *"installation"*? You are assuming that we know everything you know. There is no mention of any installers prior to your previous comment, making it fairly impossible for us to understand the semantics you meant to communicate.

Comment: The error code `0x142` is `ERROR_DEVICE_NO_RESOURCES`: "The target device has insufficient resources to complete the operation." Does that give you any hints about what the problem might be?